# Why i have migration problem in unit test but not in controller c# Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Hello i have a project web api in c# and i want to write unit test to check my controller. But i find an error that i really don't understand. When i run my method in controller

```cs
public class TherapistsController : ApiController
{
    TherapistService _therapistService = new TherapistService();
    GeneralService _generalService = new GeneralService();

    //GET: api/Therapists/GetAllTherapists
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Therapists/GetAllTherapists")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTherapist()
    {
        var therapists = _therapistService.GetAllTherapist();
        if (therapists.Count() > 0)
            return Ok(therapists);
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

it give me the result and it is fine
[image]

But if i run this method in a unit test

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllTherapistByOutletTest()
    {
        var therapists = new WebAPI.Controllers.TherapistsController();

        IHttpActionResult result = therapists.GetTherapist();

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkResult));

    }
}
```

it give me the error

[image]

Like u see the error says that i need to update database by migration but it still give me same error after i migrate and update database. But when i run the method by calling API ,it still give me the result  like the first picture and no error. I debug both ways and they have same steps until method `GetAll()` in repository  like u see in the above picture. I don't really know what wrong ?

Repository

```cs
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly SpaDbContext db;
    public GenericRepository(SpaDbContext _db)
    {
        this.db = _db;
    }
    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        db.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void Detached(TEntity entity)
    {
        db.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }    

    public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity Get(object Id)
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().Find(Id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        db.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }
```

IRepository

```cs
namespace Repository
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        TEntity Get(object Id);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        void Update(TEntity entity);

        //void Remove(object Id);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

        void Detached(TEntity entity);

        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByQuery(string query);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to 'test'?  I'm guessing EF hasn't gone through the necessary initialisation in your test when you simply new up the controller.  So you don't rely on database access in your tests, I'd advise you abstract out the services, have them as dependencies on the controller (constructor) then you can mock and assert calls on them without going near any databases.

Comment: You probably have a different connection string for each of the 2 contexts.

Comment: i  just want to test the method return ok or not . i don't understand " abstract out the services" . Can u describe how to do it briefly ?

Comment: @sellotape  i setup an online database with one connection string , i don't think i have that problem

Comment: @Van try this, I hope it makes sense https://dotnetfiddle.net/kmz925.  FYI it's pseudo code (won't compile) but should explain the concepts.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CqX3xY has an updated example with the 'abstraction' which is an interface.

Comment: @PhilCooper thanks man, i appreciate

Comment: @Van no problem, happy to help.  If you get some spare time, read up on 'dependency injection' (DI) and 'inversion of control' (IoC).  They are patterns that will serve you well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set a valid connection string in test project as web api project

Comment: yeah thank you. this is the problem , i haven't set up my connection string in  UnitTest project

Answer (score 0):

If you want do a real unit test with the controller methods you need use Mock services with this you will not have this kind of problems

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api